# Getting batch-read timeouts in aerospike : batch_queue pile up

Tags: architecture, timeout, aerospike, key-value-store

**Background:**

Am using an aerospike cluster with 9 nodes. The cluster seems to work fine but there are some intermittent timeouts for some of the batch-reads. The timeouts are occurring at server-side itself, interestingly , only on 2 out of 9 nodes. I suspected key-hotspotting to be the issue here, but seems it is not the case.

On checking the server statistics, the thing which pops up is the correlation between the batch_queue size and the timeouts.

Command : ***asadm -e "watch 1 100 show stat like batch"***

> [ 2017-09-07 20:56:10 'show stat like batch' sleep: 1.0s iteration: 47
>   of 100 ]
>
> **batch_queue                    :   586
>
>   batch_timeout                  :   81709**
>
> [ 2017-09-07 20:56:11 'show stat like batch' sleep: 1.0s iteration: 48
>   of 100 ]
>
> **batch_queue                    :   545
>
>   batch_timeout                  :   84357**
>
> [ 2017-09-07 20:56:12 'show stat like batch' sleep: 1.0s iteration: 49
>   of 100 ]
>
> **batch_queue                    :   0
>
>   batch_timeout                  :   88544**
>
> [ 2017-09-07 20:56:13 'show stat like batch' sleep: 1.0s iteration: 50
>   of 100 ]
>
> **batch_queue                    :   0
>
>   batch_timeout                  :   88544**
>
> [ 2017-09-07 20:56:14 'show stat like batch' sleep: 1.0s iteration: 51
>   of 100 ]
>
> **batch_queue                    :   0
>
>   batch_timeout                  :   88544**

There seems to be a clear correlation between the batch_queue piling up and the requests getting timeout.

**Questions**

1. What is exactly this batch queue. What is the reason of it's piling up only in a couple of aerospike nodes ?
2. How can i fix the same ?

Thanks

**Edit** :

http://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/batch.html. This answers question no.1 decently well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest, if possible (depending on client), moving over to using [batch-index](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/batch.html#batch-index). Timeouts on some of the nodes may indicate few different things:

- some nodes getting more records per batch than others
- some difference in those nodes (CPU, kernel version, storage, config) causing them to be slower
- other activity on those nodes causing them to slow down (hot keys on other read/write transactions)

Basically anything that would slow down those nodes, causing the batch queue to pile up and some batch transactions to time out.

Finally, you could try increasing the [batch-threads](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration#batch-threads) and [batch-priority](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration#batch-priority) if you haven't done so yet.